# HTTPS to HTTP redirect doesn't keep custom URL

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

Let's say I have a domain name called: [www.example.com/today.php?id=123](http://www.example.com/today.php). I got it to redirect to the url [www.example.com/yes/123/some-name](http://www.example.com/yes/123/some-name) with the following code:

```
Rewrite Rule ^yes/123/some-name$ today.php?id=123
```

But now I wanted to make that link always redirect to http when called from https. So, I tried the following code by adding:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
Rewrite Rule ^today\.php(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
```

What happens is that it get redirected to http but with the following url: www.example.com/today.php?id=123 instead of keeping the original www.example.com/yes/123/some-name. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change order of rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^yes/[^/]+/.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^yes/[^/]+/.*$ today.php?id=123 [L,QSA,NC]
```

In general keep your 301 rule before pretty rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your redirect is *before* the rule that internally routes. And you need to match against the cleaned up URL instead of the internally mapped one. So something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^yes/[0-9]+/ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]

RewriteRule ^yes/123/some-name$ today.php?id=123 [L]
```

Comment: It worked!! Thank you! But why does it work the other way around when there are no variables in the link? I am just curious because I had it the other way around for other simple urls and they worked fine.